# "an average of 1,500 lives have (or "has"?) been claimed every year": singular or plural subject?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

Should I write:

1. an average of 1,500 lives `has` been claimed every year
2. an average of 1,500 lives `have` been claimed every year

The subject of the sentence is **an average** (singular), not **1,500 lives**, so I would have intuitively used proposition 1. However, my academic advisor, who is American, told me to use proposition 2. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are being told to use (2) is that it is not *an average* that is being claimed each year, but rather *1,500 lives* that are being claimed each year. To make it clear:

> 1. **An** average **has** been claimed each year.
> 2. 1,500 **lives have** been claimed each year.

To make it clear - because the *lives are claimed*, you use the plural form of the verb, not the singular.

Firstly, let me say that [the data](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=41395959), on the general form *a/an **NOUN.sg** of * **NOUN.pl** has/had*,<sup>1</sup> supports my intuition. However, let me exemplify with some examples.

a-1. The **colors** of the rainbow **are** beautiful
a-2. The **color** of the walls **is** beautiful
b-1. An average of 1,500 **lives** **are** claimed each year
b-2. An average of one **life is** claimed each year

The primary difference between (a) and (b), is that in (a), *of* acts as as post-modifier - the subject, or perhaps *focus* of the sentence is the color, not the rainbow or the walls.

In (b), however, *of* signals a predeterminer - it quantifies the noun phrase itself, and the focus of (b) is *life/lives*.

There is some level of intuition involved here, but the main test is asking oneself what the *focus* of the phrase is - what exactly are you talking about? What is most important to the phrase? Unfortunately, there's no procedure for determining which it is in every situation.

---

<sup>1. NOUN.sg = any singular noun, NOUN.pl = any plural noun, * = any word</sup>

Comment: I clicked on your link to the Corpus, and changed the search to specifically include the word "average". The hits support your claim: _Since 2000, an average of 272 buildings **have** renewed each year; convention can be considered an undeniable success. Over the last 15 years, an average of 25 sites **have** been added to the list each year_. In the phase _"an average of X..."_, the "of X" part is not some optional prepositional phrase. Instead, it's a convenient way to say, _1500 lives are claimed each year, on average_, which is why the plural verb is used, I think.

Comment: It's certainly an interesting test; I was hoping to provide a more general rule of thumb. It wouldn't work with something like _a majority of seniors were disappointed_, for instance.

Comment: So would you say (1) `there is a virtually infinite number of buildings`, or (2) `there are a virtually infinite number of buildings`? I would say (2) to be consistent with your answer, but my advisor says (1).

Comment: Ah, _there_ does different things. Do a search and ask a new question about it.

Answer (score -1):

Have is used when you are describing a plural noun. Have is correct when you are referring to more than one thing, and has is used when you are referring to a single thing.

**A** persons **life** has been claimed.

1,5000 **lives** have been claimed.

Comment: While this is true, it is implicit in the question which refers to "an average" as singular.